# Statistically verifying distribution of users within an A/B Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, anova, variance, chi-squared-test

Hoping you can help me determine the best way to statistically verify that an A/B test was set up in an unbiased way.

The A/B test was set up to split users on my website 50/50 into a test/control group. Alongside data showing the number of users put into group A/B over time (also split out by device) I want a test to use that will allow me to say 'the split was unbiased'.

Data is in the form:

```
Date:            Group A                                   Group B
                 Users     Desktop users    Mobile users   Users   Desktop users    Mobile
1/1/15           14000     10000            4000           14200   10072           4130
2/1/15           18000     12000            6000           18150   12050           6130
3/1/15           15500     10500            5000           14900   9950            4130
```

etc

So the problem is 'assuming the proportion of users accessing the website via each device is constant each day, test for any bias within the 50/50 split'. I want to say that the user split and device influence in each group was the same, so conclusions about other factors (sales from these users) are valid.

Not sure what to use! Correlation of users in A over time against users in B over time, then correlation of desktop users in A over time against desktop users in B over time etc? And hope that all of these correlations are above 0.95? Chi-squared? ANOVA? Treat it like a coin tossing problem?

Comment: bumping this post once to attempt to get help!